# Python Recursividad Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente codigo para generar circulos de forma recursiva uno dentro de otro. Mi problema es que solo se generan 2 circulos

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

def dibujar_circulo(inicio, fin, delta):
    c.create_oval(inicio,inicio,fin,fin,fill="#ffffff",outline="#000000")

    inicio += delta 
    fin    -= delta 
    if(fin >= delta):
        print(str(inicio) + ', ' + str(fin))
        dibujar_circulo(inicio, fin, delta)

if(len(sys.argv)<3):
    print("Necesito tres argumentos: 1.- Inicio, 2.- Fin, 3.- Delta")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    inicio=int(sys.argv[1]) #1
    fin=int(sys.argv[2])    #600
    delta=int(sys.argv[3])  #5

    if(delta<1):
        delta=5

    root=tk.Tk()
    c=tk.Canvas(root,width=600,height=600)

    dibujar_circulo(inicio, fin, delta)

    c.pack()
    c.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que dibujas el doble de círculos de los que deberías, y todos ellos tienen un relleno opaco.

Me explico. Con los parámetros que indicas (1, 600, 5) el radio del círculo exterior sería de 300 (la mitad de 600), por lo que deberían dibujarse 300/5 = 60 círculos concéntricos. Es decir, detenerse cuando se llegue al círculo central.

Sin embargo, tal como lo has hecho, una vez alcanzado el círculo central continúas dibujando círculos, ahora cada vez mayores, hasta que el último círculo usa `inicio=596`, `fin=5`. Cada uno de estos círculos, debido al relleno opaco blanco, va tapando a los dibujados previamente por lo que al final sólo se ven dos (ya que el inicial, el exterior, no se redibuja).

Tienes dos soluciones: eliminar el parámetro `fill=` al hacer cada círculo, para que durante el redibujado no se tapen, o cambiar la condición que finaliza las llamadas recursivas, para que sea `abs(fin-inicio)/2>delta`.

Por ejemplo, para generar la siguiente figura he puesto la condición que te acabo de indicar, y como color de relleno `#ffffcc` para que no sea blanco y así se vea que sí que he usado un relleno:

[image: Resultado]